# Sending Email Problem : Connection refused

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to send email to the user when registering. 
But its generating an error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25".

Currently I have add this to the web.config

```
 <system.net> 
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network
          host="localhost"
          port="25"
          defaultCredentials="true"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Do you have correctly SMTP server installed? Try some remote server.

Comment: Check with gmail smtp host = smtp.gmail.com 
Use Authentication: Yes
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
Port for SSL: 465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by `Ben Robinson` and `Ernest Friedman-Hill` you need to have `SMTP` server installed on your local machine. Otherwise you can use any other host.

```
   <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="yourMailId@gmail.com ">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" defaultCredentials="false"
      port="587" userName ="yourMailId@gmail.com" password="yourMailPassword" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
```

I used `gmail` as a host here.

While using this Don't forget to enable the SSL

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: Welcome, then [accept this as a answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Also, you can give `upvote` for other helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your application needs to talk to a functioning mail (SMTP) server. Your configuration indicates there's one installed on your local machine, but apparently there is not. Either install and configure one, or change "localhost" to point to a host where one actually exists,.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you there is no SMTP server listening on port 25 on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your app is looking for an SMTP server on your own machine. You'll need to either install an SMTP server on your machine or use your ISP's SMTP server.